# How to wait an Elixir spawned process to end like Ruby's Thread#join

Tags: ruby, multithreading, elixir

I have a following Ruby code:

```
t = Thread.new do
  sleep(1)
  puts "Finished!"
end

t.join
```

How can I write an equivalent code in Elixir?

I wrote the following one:

```
spawn fn ->
  :timer.sleep(1000)
  IO.puts "Finished!"
end

:timer.sleep(1000)
```

It works but this is not equivalent to the Ruby version.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of aiming for something as equivalent as possible, here's what I'd consider a more idiomatic approach to the problem of "run a background process that sleeps for a second, and don't exit the script until it finishes."

```
Task.async(fn -> :timer.sleep(1000) end)
|> Task.await
```

Answer (score 15):

You can use `Process.monitor/1` and `receive` for this:

```
pid = spawn(fn ->
  :timer.sleep(1000)
  IO.puts "Finished!"
end)

# Start monitoring `pid`
ref = Process.monitor(pid)

# Wait until the process monitored by `ref` is down.
receive do
  {:DOWN, ^ref, _, _, _} ->
    IO.puts "Process #{inspect(pid)} is down"
end
```

Output:

```
Finished!
Process #PID<0.73.0> is dead
```

`Process #PID<0.73.0> is dead` is printed just after `Finished!`.

Comment: It worth it to mention that it’s still not an equivalent of Ruby version, and none would be, since there is a significant difference between threads and processes.

Comment: and if there were several spawned processes?

Comment: @アレックス You could wrap the code in a function that accepts a `pid` as an argument and call the function for each process (`pid` value).

Answer (score -3):

I think this can give you some clue:

```
# save in a spawner.ex file
for _ <- 1..10 do                                                                                   
  spawn(fn ->                                                                                       
    pid = self()                                                                                    
    ms = Enum.random(1..1000)                                                                       

    :timer.sleep(ms)                                                                                
    IO.puts "#{inspect(pid)} finished in #{ms}ms"                                                  
  end)                                                                                              
end                                                                                                 

:timer.sleep(2000)                                                                                  
IO.puts "Jobs done, thanks!"
```

which will output something like:

```
iex(12)> c "./spawner.ex"
#PID<0.179.0> finished in 21ms
#PID<0.180.0> finished in 102ms
#PID<0.185.0> finished in 113ms
#PID<0.183.0> finished in 273ms
#PID<0.178.0> finished in 400ms
#PID<0.182.0> finished in 671ms
#PID<0.184.0> finished in 751ms
#PID<0.186.0> finished in 933ms
#PID<0.187.0> finished in 936ms
#PID<0.181.0> finished in 985ms
Jobs done, thanks!
[]
iex(13)>
```

Comment: Timer doesn't allow you to determine a process has finished, it only helps you to guess, which may not be correct.